# errorhandler layout in yii not rendering

Tags: yii

searched around. The layouts doesn't render.

Things I've tried:

1. changed the layout path. Doesn't render.
2. create init, `Yii::app()->errorHandler->errorAction='site/error';` and changed to
   something like `errorAction='hi'`. Which did respond to say can't
   find hi.
3. Went to site/error file and typed hi in view,.. it never says hi to me :(
4. created protected/views/system and changed the error files. Nothing.
5. Also followed the first answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815543/yii-how-to-handle-custom-404-error-page-along-with-other-error-pages) page
6. main config is `'errorAction'=>'site/error',`

> ```
> public function actionError()
>         {
>           $this->layout = 'main'; //also tried '//layouts/main'
>           if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
>           {
>               if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
>                   echo $error['message'];
>               else
>                   $this->render('error', $error);
>           }
>           else
>               throw new CHttpException(404, 'Page not found.');
>         }
> ```

Comment: Don't throw a 404, when a 404 is thrown you will get to that action, and by throwing another one your getting in a loop. Also, please post some errors your getting.

Comment: oh okay... Hm, but I'm not getting errors. Well I want the errors. It is CHttpException You are not authorized to perform this action. I want to customize this page.